# Elliptic Curve Points in sagemath

Tags: sage

I want to implement Pollard_Lambda for finding discrete log of an elliptic curve point in sage. 
for dividing elliptic points in three sections I need to compare y coordinates of elliptic point.So is there any function in sage witch can separate our x and y coordinates of elliptic point pleaze tell me
---Santosh Javheri

Comment: Is this programming related? If, so please provide what you have tried so far, otherwise we suggest you post your question to the [math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It is actually fairly simple to divide a point on an elliptic curve into its x and y coordinates. Here's how it goes for example, on a 'random' Elliptic Curve over a finite field F<sub>q</sub>:

```
q = (2 ** 255) - 19 
E = EllipticCurve(GF(q),[0,486662,0,1,0])
point = E([yourXCoordinate,yourYCoordinate]) #any point you'd like on E
x,y = point.xy() #the function you asked for
```

Hope that helps